# How do I document parallel computations within knitr implemented in Rstudio?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, knitr

I'm coding an agent-based simulation. I plan to run parallel instances of the simulation to reduce computing time. I will use the parallel package. I want to document my code using knitr. Before I start, I'd like to confirm whether there will be any issues running the parallel package's functions from within a Markdown or Sweave document that I compile with knitr.

Comment: Sorry but a vague answer to a vague question: learn it (be "it" knitr or Markdown or whatever).

Comment: Well, @Thell, the first step for me was two-fold: (a) Ask this question, (b) do exactly what you did. In cases like this, I find that asking a question is perfectly fine, because perhaps there is some unforeseen issue using the parallel package with knitr that doesn't result in a runtime error, but might cause me woe somewhere down the road. Thank you very much for the comment, but I'm not the college undergrad asking for homework help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works...

#### Parallel Example in RStudio as run via knitr after being written in R markdown...

`````
```{r parallel-do}
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
demo(sincParallel)
````
`````

See output on Rpubs::

http://rpubs.com/Thell/6679