# Knitting markdown with parallel processes in RStudio

Tags: r, parallel-processing, fork, rstudio, knitr

Given the `parallel` package's warning against using `mclapply()` in GUI environments, I've been moving away from using RStudio for scripts calling that function. I think I've observed (though I can't test for) a performance improvement.

I realize that [knitting markdown documents with parallel processes works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17245762/7428812) in RStudio, as does running `mclapply()` in RStudio, much of the time. But can I expect better performance if I knit through Terminal, instead of through RStudio? Or might RStudio's calls to `knit()` not actually fork the GUI? If so, could calling `source()` from RStudio's Console be safe as well?

Unfortunately, I don't know how to reproduce the problems that (sometimes?) occur when forking through a GUI, so I haven't been able to run any tests myself. So perhaps a better question is, can anyone think of a systematic method of testing for which types of function calls will result in these problems?

For reference: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf. (See point 2 in the introduction.)

Comment: The GUI is *never* forked. And as long as your threads don’t attempt to communicate with the GUI there should be no problem using `mclapply`, neither via kitting nor via normal script execution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, am I misunderstanding the warning in the `parallel` package documentation, then? When is it safe to use a GUI and when is it not?

Comment: You're not misunderstanding it, the warning in the documentation is just very broad and, I think, being overly cautious. Which is a shame, I’d prefer if they gave a detailed explanation of what exact function calls would cause problems.

Comment: @KonradRudolph hmm, okay. I'll edit the question, leave it open for now, and see if anyone can provide that explanation for us. Thanks for the advice.